# Java: setting variable on object array

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
public class ParkingLotApplication {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static ParkingDescription[][] ParkingLot = new ParkingDescription[3][15];
public StudentDescription StudDesc = new StudentDescription();
static int i = 0;
static int j = 0;
static int parkLevel = 0;
static int parkSlot = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO: Add your code here
    ParkingLotApplication PA = new ParkingLotApplication();
    PA.menu();
}

public void menu() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("WELCOME TO CAR PARK SYSTEM");
    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    String nm = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your password: ");
    int pass = input.nextInt();
    if ((nm.equals("admin12")) && (pass == 12345)) {
        Login();
    } else {
        menu();
    }
}

public void Login() {
    System.out.println("|----------------------------------|");
    System.out.println("|           Admin Menu             |");
    System.out.println("|----------------------------------|");
    System.out.println("|  N- New Registration             |");
    System.out.println("|  U- Update Data                  |");
    System.out.println("|----------------------------------|");
    char ch = input.next().charAt(0);
    switch (ch) {
        case 'N':
        case 'n':
            Reg();
            break;

        case 'U':
        case 'u':
            UpdatePark();
            break;


        default:
            System.out.println("Choose Again!");
            Login();
            break;
    }
}

public void Reg() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("                               **Parking Lot**        ");
    System.out.println("    ________________________________________________________________________________");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
            ParkingLot[i][j] = new ParkingDescription();
            System.out.print("   *   " + ParkingLot[i][j].getStatus());
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("    ********************************************************************************");
    }
    System.out.println("Please insert number 1-3 to choose the parking level");
    parkLevel = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please insert number 1-15 to choose the parking slot");
    parkSlot = input.nextInt();

    //check available
    if (parkLevel == 1) {
        ParkingLot[0][parkSlot - 1] = new ParkingDescription();
        if (ParkingLot[0][parkSlot - 1].getAvailable() == true) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter tp: ");
            int tp = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please Enter First Name: ");
            String ft = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Last Name: ");
            String lt = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Contact Number: ");
            int cn = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Email Address: ");
            String ea = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Car Number: ");
            String cnb = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Date Registered : ");
            int date = input.nextInt();

            StudDesc.setStudDesc(tp, ft, lt, cn, ea, cnb, date);

            int pID = (parkLevel * 1000) + parkSlot;
            ParkingLot[0][parkSlot - 1].setPark(pID, false, StudDesc);
            System.out.println("Thanks");
            menu();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry");
            menu();
        }
    } else if (parkLevel == 2) {
        ParkingLot[1][parkSlot - 1] = new ParkingDescription();
        if (ParkingLot[1][parkSlot - 1].getAvailable() == true) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter tp: ");
            int tp = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please Enter First Name: ");
            String ft = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Last Name: ");
            String lt = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Contact Number: ");
            int cn = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Email Address: ");
            String ea = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Car Number: ");
            String cnb = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Date Registered : ");
            int date = input.nextInt();

            StudDesc.setStudDesc(tp, ft, lt, cn, ea, cnb, date);

            int pID = (parkLevel * 1000) + parkSlot;
            ParkingLot[1][parkSlot - 1].setPark(pID, false, StudDesc);
            System.out.println("Thanks");
            menu();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry");
            menu();
        }
    } else if (parkLevel == 3) {
        ParkingLot[2][parkSlot - 1] = new ParkingDescription();
        if (ParkingLot[2][parkSlot - 1].getAvailable() == true) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter tp: ");
            int tp = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please Enter First Name: ");
            String ft = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Last Name: ");
            String lt = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Contact Number: ");
            int cn = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Email Address: ");
            String ea = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Car Number: ");
            String cnb = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Date Registered : ");
            int date = input.nextInt();

            StudDesc.setStudDesc(tp, ft, lt, cn, ea, cnb, date);

            int pID = (parkLevel * 1000) + parkSlot;
            ParkingLot[2][parkSlot - 1].setPark(pID, false, StudDesc);
            System.out.println("Thanks");
            menu();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry");
            menu();
        }
    }
}

public void UpdatePark() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("                                     **Parking Lot**                   ");
    System.out.println("    ________________________________________________________________________________");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
            ParkingLot[i][j] = new ParkingDescription();
            System.out.print("   *   " + ParkingLot[i][j].getStatus());
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("    ********************************************************************************");
    }
    System.out.println("Please insert number 1-3 to choose the parking level");
    parkLevel = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please insert number 1-15 to choose the parking slot");
    parkSlot = input.nextInt();

    //check available
    if (parkLevel == 1) {
        ParkingLot[0][parkSlot - 1] = new ParkingDescription();
        if (ParkingLot[0][parkSlot - 1].getAvailable() == false) {
            ParkingLot[0][parkSlot - 1].showDetails();
            menu();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry");
            menu();
        }
    } else if (parkLevel == 2) {
        ParkingLot[1][parkSlot - 1] = new ParkingDescription();
        if (ParkingLot[1][parkSlot - 1].getAvailable() == true) {
            ParkingLot[1][parkSlot - 1].showDetails();
            menu();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry");
            menu();
        }
    } else if (parkLevel == 3) {
        ParkingLot[2][parkSlot - 1] = new ParkingDescription();
        if (ParkingLot[2][parkSlot - 1].getAvailable() == true) {
            ParkingLot[2][parkSlot - 1].showDetails();
            menu();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry");
            menu();
        }
    }
}
  }

//Class parking description
public class ParkingDescription {

public static int StudID, ParkSpaceID, DReg;
public static String Status, CNum;
 public static Boolean Available = true;

  public ParkingDescription() {
// TODO: Add your code here
 }

public void setPark(int parkSpaceID, Boolean available, StudentDescription StDe)
{
  this.StudID = StDe.getStudentID();
  this.CNum = StDe.getCarNumber();
  this.DReg = StDe.getDateReg();
  this.ParkSpaceID = parkSpaceID;
  this.Available = available;
}

public Boolean getAvailable()
{
  return Available;
}

public String getStatus()
{
  if(Available == false){
    return "1";
  } else {
    return "0";
  }
}

  public void showDetails()
{
  //generate report
  System.out.println("Student ID : TP"+StudID);
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Car Number : "+CNum);
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Parking Space : L"+ParkSpaceID);
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Date Register : "+DReg);
}
}
 //Student class

 public class StudentDescription {

 public int StudentID, CNumber, DateReg;
 public String FName, LName, EMail, CarNum;

 public StudentDescription() {
// TODO: Add your code here
 }
   public void setStudDesc(int studentID, String fName, String lName, int cNumber, String eMail, String carNum, int dateReg)
{
  this.StudentID = studentID;
  this.FName = fName;
  this.LName = lName;
  this.CNumber = cNumber;
  this.EMail = eMail;
  this.CarNum = carNum;
  this.DateReg = dateReg;
}

public int getStudentID()
{
  return this.StudentID;
}

public String getCarNumber()
{
  return this.CarNum;
}

public int getDateReg()
{
  return this.DateReg;
}
 }
```

I have this problem. when i want to set one parking detail object into ParkingLot array, the array is insert same data information on all of array. the output suppose to be like this:

```
**Parking Lot**                   
*   1   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0  *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0
*   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0     *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0
*   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0   *   0
```

but I got all the output being set to 1. So how to solve this problem? thanks..

Comment: Can you show us all of your code please?  Not just the part where YOU think the problem is?

Comment: i already edited my code above. please check again. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's still lots of code that you haven't shown, for example, the code for the `ParkingDescription` class.  But based on what you HAVE shown ...

In the chunk of code that prints out all the statuses, (which for some reason, you've coded twice - once in `Reg` and once in `UpdatePark`), you are populating your array with 45 new `ParkingDescription` objects, and printing the status of each one.  That is, you're throwing away all the `ParkingDescription` objects that you had previously, and only printing brand new objects.  You really don't want to do that, because it's the `ParkingDescription` objects that store all the data that the user has entered.

I guess you're getting all 1s because 1 is the status of a new `ParkingDescription`.

**UPDATE**

Now that you've shown your `ParkingDescription` class, I see that the problem is that you've declared its fields as `static`.  That means that there's only one copy of each field, shared between all the instances of this class.  Remove the word `static` from the field declarations, and the problem should be fixed.

And the next time you post a question on Stack Overflow, I strongly recommend posting ALL the code when you first post the question.  Don't just post the part where YOU think the bug is, because you waste everyone's time if you're wrong.

Comment: that's what I thought, variable for ParkingDescritption class only set details parking slot such as name, car number and email. so my next qeustion is where exactly I need to put **ParkingLot[i][j]= new ParkingDescription()** so that the object can access on different function (on global variable). Thanks

Comment: Basically, I think you should remove ALL your lines that say `something = new ParkingDescription();`, and create your 45 `ParkingDescription` objects _either_ in a constructor of `ParkingLotApplication`, _or_ in a separate method which you call just before `PA.menu()`.

Comment: So, I just need to add like this for the constructor?
**public ParkingLotApplication()
  {for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {for(j=0;j<15;j++)
        {ParkingLot[i][j] = new ParkingDescription();}
      }
  }**

Comment: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: but I still have same problem. my thought for the problem is on the Reg function where the object is being set

Comment: Did you remove EVERY other place where you had written `new ParkingDescription();` ?

Comment: OK, the next thing I can think of to try is to step through this code with a debugger.  It really should have been the first thing, but never mind.  You'll then be able to see exactly what it is that you're printing.  I would do it myself, but you STILL haven't posted all of your code - you don't have your `ParkingDescription` or `StudentDescription` classes, so I can't build and run your program.

Comment: i already edited my source code above. i added all my code including studentclass and parkingdescription class. please check again, thanks.

Comment: thank you so much for your time to help me, i just starting my programming study this year. And thanks for the suggestion, next time i will post my whole code.